# PHP Array not iterating properly, only grabs first result

Tags: php, arrays

This is interesting none the less, left me stumped. I have an array of 'order' objects called Workday, if I print_r the array I get the following;

```
Workday Object
(
    [workday] => Array
        (
            [0] => Order Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [date] => 2013-08-02
                    [username] => userXYZ
                    [number] => 33333333 
                    [duration_start] => 20:51:00
                    [duration_end] => 21:51:00
                    [total] => $340.00
                )

            [1] => Order Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [date] => 2013-08-03
                    [username] => userXXA
                    [number] => 87653212 
                    [duration_start] => 10:51:00
                    [duration_end] => 11:54:00
                    [total] => $20.00
                )

            [2] => Order Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [date] => 2013-08-01
                    [username] => userXYD
                    [number] => 12345678 
                    [duration_start] => 08:37:00
                    [duration_end] => 10:01:00
                    [total] => $10.00
                )

        )

)
```

The issue seems to be when I try to iterate over the array it only outputs the first result. What am I missing?

```
$workday = new Workday();
$workday->Get($username, $duration_start, $duration_end);

$i = 0;
if($workday != null)
{
    foreach($workday as $orders)
    {
        echo "ID: " . $orders[$i]->number;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried, got Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Workday as array

Comment: Are you sure that is not your `Get()` method that returns only one result? Do you pass `$username, $duration_start,$duration_end` as search parameters because this might add up why you only receive one result.

Comment: @DaveChen your answer was correct, why did you delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($workday->workday as $orders)
    {
        echo "ID: " . $orders->number;
     }
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you... so is my array poorly designed or just a n00b dev oversight. :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the `workday` member variable of your object

```
if($workday != null)
{
    foreach($workday['workday'] as $orders)
    {
        echo "ID: " . $orders->number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is telling what's going on: you're trying to use an object as an array. Iterate over `$workday->workday` instead (which is the array inside your object).

```
foreach ($workday->workday as $orders) { ... }
```